# How do i target multi parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

How do i target the parent class="cccc" or id="99" in jquery?

```
<div id="11" class="aaaa">
    <div id="22" class="bbbb">
        <div style="display: block;">
            <h5>
                    <p id="34">something</p>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="88" style="float: right;">
            <div class="cccc" id="99">
               UFF
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>   
</div>
```

I have tried this code.

```
$('#88').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('#11').find('#99').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$('#88').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('#99').click();
});
```

Comment: If he needs to check for both elements, I would go with your answer but also adding the class element thus "$(this).find('#99, .cccc').click();"

Comment: He just edit title's post but the content still write `target the element`. :(

Comment: Yeah, he made it quite unclear now, the elements he wants to target from #88 are not parents but children...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fire click event of a child element, you can do as below. This is better since you have to travel a single level down the DOM tree.

```html
$('#88').on('click', function() {
    $(this).children('#99').click();
});
```

Since you have mentioned something about accessing parents, I will post how to access parents as well.

```html
$('#88').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('.aaa').css( "background-color", "red" );
    //$(this).parents('.aaa').click();
});
```